# SCIP Solver Running Indefinitely

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, scip

I am Using the SCIP interactive shell, to solve a problem from an LP file, the solver is running since hours with no improvements in optimality GAP, normally this MIP problem is solved by free Solvers in under one second.

Here is part of console log it's same for hours

```
 7564s|682700 |669166 | 20689k|  30.3 |4674M| 241 | 110 |1276 |1664 |1276 |1395 |   1 |  31k|  20k| 2.876849e+05 | 2.342078e+05 |  22.83%
 7565s|682800 |669266 | 20693k|  30.3 |4675M| 241 |  61 |1276 |1670 |1276 |1395 |   1 |  31k|  20k| 2.876849e+05 | 2.342078e+05 |  22.83%
 7565s|682900 |669354 | 20699k|  30.3 |4675M| 241 | 129 |1276 |1687 |1276 |1395 |   1 |  31k|  20k| 2.876849e+05 | 2.342078e+05 |  22.83%
 7566s|683000 |669454 | 20701k|  30.3 |4675M| 241 | 102 |1276 |1677 |1276 |1395 |   1 |  31k|  20k| 2.876849e+05 | 2.342078e+05 |  22.83%
 7567s|683100 |669554 | 20706k|  30.3 |4675M| 241 | 149 |1276 |1677 |1276 |1395 |   1 |  31k|  20k| 2.876849e+05 | 2.342078e+05 |  22.83%
 7567s|683200 |669652 | 20709k|  30.3 |4676M| 241 | 106 |1276 |1666 |1276 |1395 |   1 |  31k|  20k| 2.876849e+05 | 2.342078e+05 |  22.83%
 7568s|683300 |669746 | 20713k|  30.3 |4676M| 241 | 112 |1276 |1660 |1276 |1395 |   1 |  31k|  20k| 2.876849e+05 | 2.342078e+05 |  22.83%
 7569s|683400 |669834 | 20716k|  30.3 |4679M| 241 | 139 |1276 |1656 |1276 |1395 |   1 |  31k|  20k| 2.876849e+05 | 2.342078e+05 |  22.83%
 7569s|683500 |669934 | 20721k|  30.3 |4680M| 241 |  93 |1276 |1649 |1276 |1395 |   1 |  31k|  20k| 2.876849e+05 | 2.342078e+05 |  22.83%
 time | node  | left  |LP iter|LP it/n| mem |mdpt |frac |vars |cons |cols |rows |cuts |confs|strbr|  dualbound   | primalbound  |  gap   
 7570s|683600 |670034 | 20724k|  30.3 |4680M| 241 |  92 |1276 |1646 |1276 |1395 |   1 |  31k|  20k| 2.876849e+05 | 2.342078e+05 |  22.83%
 7571s|683700 |670134 | 20727k|  30.3 |4680M| 241 |  78 |1276 |1643 |1276 |1395 |   1 |  31k|  20k| 2.876848e+05 | 2.342078e+05 |  22.83%
 7571s|683800 |670234 | 20730k|  30.3 |4681M| 241 | 141 |1276 |1649 |1276 |1395 |   1 |  31k|  20k| 2.876848e+05 | 2.342078e+05 |  22.83%
 7572s|683900 |670318 | 20733k|  30.3 |4682M| 241 |   - |1276 |1642 |1276
```

Is there is some kind termination parameter that I am missing, apart form time limit and optimality gap as they provide the non-global solution

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are asking for, but you can have a look at other termination limits by typing `set limits` in the interactive shell.

Comment: I am asking, that i need to provide scip some way to stop, as MIP GAP is not decreasing. What are those ways

Comment: Which other free solvers have you tried? Feel free to write to the SCIP mailing list and send your model.

Comment: Coin or cbc and glpk

Comment: Try to perturb the problem a little bit.Also I have seen LP files being interpreted somewhat differently between solvers. An MPS file is safer when using different solvers.

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem while solving some instances of my model. Did you find a way to stop the solver when this happens?

Comment: I'm having the problem as well..@orpanter @Manish Did you get any luck?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have full control over the solving process, then you could use an event handler to check the progress in the dual and primal bound by yourself. [Here](https://scip.zib.de/doc-6.0.2/html/EVENTHDLR_MAIN.php) you find an example that shows how to add an event handler to SCIP. In your case, I would suggest catching the `SCIP_EVENTTYPE_NODESOLVED` event, which is thrown after processing each node of the branch-and-bound tree.